# 1950s or 60s story about a world on a baseball

Tags: story-identification

I've been trying to track down a story my mom remembers reading when she was young.

The bulk of the story or book (not sure if it's a short story or novel) is about people you think are on Earth. They discover that a meteor is going to crash into the planet, so they build ships to get everyone off before the planet is destroyed. Just as the meteor is about to hit and they're taking off, the story switches to two boys playing baseball. One boy comments that the strangest thing just happened: just as the ball was about to hit his mitt, a cloud of dust blew off of it, leaving the reader to realize that all along, what they thought was Earth was really a microscopic civilization on the ball or mitt.

Does this sound familiar to anyone?

Answer (score 14):

This story is from the Marvel Comics anthology *Where Creatures Roam*, [issue #7](http://www.comicvine.com/where-creatures-roam-7/4000-11555/), from July 1971.

Images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

All credit should go to [Reddit user ruwawth](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/3f234o/tomtmovietv_episodemovie_where_people_escape_a/ctl2492) for tracking this down.