# Story about a planet that turns out to be a baseball

Tags: story-identification

Do you know of a story about a planet (possibly earth) that is about to be destroyed by a meteor, so the occupants of the planet build ships and evacuate it, right as the occupants take off the story shifts to a baseball with a layer of "dust" escaping it. Turns out the planet ends up being a baseball, and the dust are the inhabitants.

The entire story takes place between the pitch release and the catch of a non professional baseball game.

Comment: Somebody on Reddit figured it out! I've posted it as an answer to the other question.

Comment: Per the [recent Meta](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7067/20774) on the subject, we don't close as dupe unless there are accepted answers on both questions

Comment: @Richard could a mod look at the IPs and verify that these are very likely duplicate accounts?

Comment: @David You should post the same answer here. Maybe at least one of them will get accepted.

Comment: @SQB Do mods have that much power?? Maybe Leigh and Katie are sisters and they both heard about this story from their mom?

Answer (score 4):

This story is from the Marvel Comics anthology *Where Creatures Roam*, [issue #7](http://www.comicvine.com/where-creatures-roam-7/4000-11555/), from July 1971.

Images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

All credit should go to [Reddit user ruwawth](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/3f234o/tomtmovietv_episodemovie_where_people_escape_a/ctl2492) for tracking this down.

(copied my answer from [this apparent duplicate question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/90298/1950s-or-60s-story-about-a-world-on-a-baseball))